# Error installing mysql-server Debian

Tags: debian, mysql

I've been trying to install mysql-server on my Debian system, and every time the server gets to installing mysql-server-5.5 it always hiccups here

```
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-client (5.5.31+dfsg-0+wheezy1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: these may help: https://superuser.com/questions/618358 and http://mygamingtalk.com/forums/topic/2560-upgrading-from-mysql-server-51-to-55-debian/

Comment: first step seems to be to check for error messages in /var/log/syslog